# How to install sublime monokai theme in netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans, installation, themes

this is source link but not say how to install, thanks in advance.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55859/sublime-monokai-theme-for-netbeans-8

Comment: !*!*!*!*!*!*!*!*!*!*! And the perfect complement for this dark editor is a grey skin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/46003/dark-nimbus-theme *!*!*!*!*!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to import the theme through options.

1. ***Download*** the theme from there
2. ***Start NetBeans*** an go to the ***Options*** (**`Tools -> Options`**)
3. ***Import*** the ***theme settings*** (**`Import...`**)
4. ***Select*** the ***downloaded archive***; if net selected yet, ***select all***
5. Ok

If your theme doesn't change, you can change themes in **`Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Profile`**.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu and there's no 'Fonts & Colors' option

Comment: That's strange, can you post a screenshot of your options window?

Answer (score 5):

On Mac and Netbeans 8.1, you need to open 
**Netbeans -> Preferences -> Font $ Colors**

There is a button for **Import**.

Just select the zip you downloaded from plugins.netbeans.org and it will add your new theme after restart.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans 8.2

- Tools > Options
- Press the "Import" button
- Browse the theme
- Press ok
  [image]